# Magento2: save new order by different order status

Tags: magento, magento2

I've created a new payment gateway but I would like to save a different order status

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Vendor_CustomPayment',
__DIR__
```

);

etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <payment>
        <custompayment>
            <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
            <is_gateway>1</is_gateway>
            <model>Vendor\CustomPayment\Model\PaymentMethod</model>
            <active>1</active>
            <title>Pay with Credit Card</title>
            <order_status>Pending</order_status>
        </custompayment>
    </payment>
</default>
```

However, when I try to make order I doesn't see Pending status but Processing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by my self adding this variable in the Payment Model:

```
protected $_isInitializeNeeded = true;
```

this code overrides Order::STATE_PROCESSING defined in: **Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment**